# Could not access db.php into another php page

Tags: php

Below is a `db.php` file where i do the connection of my database.

```
<?php
  $db_name="dbname";
  $mysql_user="user";
  $mysql_pass="123";
  $server_name="127.0.0.1";
  $con = mysql_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name) or die ("could not connect database"); 
?>
```

Another php page where I am including the `db.php` page, but connection is not happening:

```
include "db.php";       
if(!$con ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}       
else  {}
```

The code enters `if` loop.

error message : `Could not connect:`

Both `db.php` and `sample.php` are in the same folder

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Is `db.php` on same path as your php page? If there was some error in the connection, it would have caught in db.php itself by the statement `or die ("could not connect database");`

Comment: Use `require` instead of `include`, as it'll provide an error if it fails.

Comment: i tried with require also

Comment: If the connection fails, it would never enter the `if` part, since it will `die` in the first section.

Comment: I dont think that using mysql_connect() you can connect database properly. –

Comment: @ShreyasBhandimatt yes

Comment: what is this??? are you working in wordpress or core php??

Comment: am working in wordpress . sample.php is my custom template

Comment: then why are you create db.php???

Comment: Your issue is solved I have sent you complete thing.

Comment: Stop using depreciated `mysql_` functions!! You should not be using `mysql_connect` as it is a _depreciated_ function. you should be using `mysqli_connect()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of db.php
For current code, Both db.php and calling (current) file must be in same folder.

Debug code using  ***include()***

```
$test=include('db.php');
var_dump($test);
```

It should return ***true***.

Comment: The code enters if loop. means no problem in including .

Comment: @ShreyasBhandimatt  Then issue is realted to  db setting. Please use $server_name="localhost"; and check db name and password

Answer (score 0):

by removing the or die() at db.php because you call it twice or just exclude the if condition.

```
<?php
$db_name="dbname";
$mysql_user="user";
$mysql_pass="123";
$server_name="127.0.0.1";
$con = mysql_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 
?>

include "db.php";       
if(!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}       
else  {}
```

Comment: what php versio your are using. mysql_connect was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

Comment: @Dreathlord You wouldn't even end up in the `if` statement since you would get a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

If your script inside wordpress environment,( in wp-content)

You have always use **global $wpdb** object.

```
global $wpdb; //you database is connected

// perform operation
```

If  your script is outside the Wordpress environment, what you want to do is initiate it before using the defines in wp-config.

```
require_once(path/to/wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

**If you need Separate Database file then,**

create file inside theme directory.

use function to call.

```
get_template_directory_uri().'db.php';
```

Comment: No @VasimVanzara data is not getting inserted.  No errors also

Comment: you are mixup both things core and wordpress

Answer (score -2):

you will need to write mysql_error() as mysql_error($con).

Comment: Why are you suggesting to use a depreciated function? This is a bad answer.

Comment: Stop using depreciated mysql_ functions!! You should not be using `mysqli_`  or PDO functions instead! Read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)